# How to update existing template row in HTML/JS

Tags: javascript, html, flask

I'm considering using a template to dynamically create rows in a web application to gradually update the page as the server sends new data after it finishes its calculations. Creating new rows with the template works fine, but I was wondering how I could update the information in existing rows created using the template, or if it is even possible to update existing rows using templates.

```
                    <!-- reusable template for row objects -->
                    <template id="post_template">
                        <!-- template content -->
                        <div class="card mb-3 animated fadeIn shadow-sm">
                             <div class="cared-body"> 
                                 <h4 class="card-title" id="title"></h4>
                                 <span class="text-muted" id="content"></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </template>
```

Comment: Instead of your server side function appending rows to the end of the list, just have it replace all the rows.

Comment: Replacing every row is unideal. I am asking for a method to identify and update a specific row element as procedurally regenerating hundreds to thousands of rows, especially if they include heavy elements like images, would impede performance.

Comment: Then just write an "innerRow" function to replace the inner contents of rows, and use JavaScript and AJAX to target those rows and replace.